# extjs treenode add radio group as node property

Tags: extjs, radio-button, extjs3, treenode

I'd like this effect.

[image]

I wouldn't like `Take a nap` show as a non-leaf node with `10 minutes` and `20 minutes` show as leaf child nodes of `Take a nap` node.

I try with code

```
    children: [{
        text: 'Take a nap <input type="radio" checked/>10 minutes<input type="radio"/>20 minutes',
        leaf: true,
    },{......}]
```

It can show as my expection. But can not work since the radio button can't be clicked.

And I don't like implement with menu like this:

```
    var menu1 = new Ext.menu.Menu({
        items: [
        '<b class="menu-title">Choose Time</b>',
        {
            text: '10 minutes',
            checked: true,
            group: 'time'
        }, {
            text: '20 minutes',
            checked: false,
            group: 'time'
        }]
    });

    children: [{
        text: 'Go jogging',
        leaf: true,

        listeners: {
            'click': function(node,event) {

                x = event.browserEvent.clientX;
                y = event.browserEvent.clientY;
                menu1.showAt([x, y]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Can extjs do this?

Demo In [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aylwynlake/jymfxq13/), for convenience.

Comment: Not out of the box, you would need to modify the cell rendering, which depends on the version. That looks like Ext3?

Comment: Yes. My team use ext3.4. It's very old.